# css width inherited from inline-block element

Tags: html, css

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
div {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #f3f3f3;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
    <p>Sed salvia readymade, pour-over delectus art party raw denim consequat. Man bun pinterest nisi, incididunt flexitarian try-hard mollit fugiat asymmetrical bushwick waistcoat et synth organic brooklyn.</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

I want the `<div>` to be centered and to have the same width as the `<h1>`.
The same thing with the text, but how can I set the width of the `<p>`to be the same as the `<h1>`?

Comment: When you set any width for the `div` everything auto-adjusts and works how it should. Why do you have such a requirement, may I ask?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this you can use `display: table` on `div` and set its `width` to `1%`. After that you just use `white-space: nowrap` on `h1` so it will stay in one line and text of `p` element will adjust to that width.

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1%;
}
h1 {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
  <p>Sed salvia readymade, pour-over delectus art party raw denim consequat. Man bun pinterest nisi, incididunt flexitarian try-hard mollit fugiat asymmetrical bushwick waistcoat et synth organic brooklyn.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

With `width: 0` you can make the parent div shrink ignoring the paragraph, only taking the header into consideration. And then with `min-width: 100%` you can force it to be as wide as the div.

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
div {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #f3f3f3;
}
p {
  width: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
  <p>Sed salvia readymade, pour-over delectus art party raw denim consequat. Man bun pinterest nisi, incididunt flexitarian try-hard mollit fugiat asymmetrical bushwick waistcoat et synth organic brooklyn.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

body

```
{
text-align:center;
}
```

div

```
{
width:200px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #f3f3f3;
}
```

div p

```
{
text-align:justify;
}
```